# How to override TraceableAdapter in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony5

There are any ways to override Symfony's `TraceableAdapter` and use mine instead of `Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TraceableAdapter`?
I don't have any idea [because of](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/91b40b0a8820236c29723b6f2961c0455179fa06/src/Symfony/Component/Cache/DependencyInjection/CacheCollectorPass.php#L68):

```
$recorder = new Definition(is_subclass_of($definition->getClass(), TagAwareAdapterInterface::class) ? TraceableTagAwareAdapter::class : TraceableAdapter::class);
```

Comment: The traceable adapter is only used when debugging is enabled and wraps around the existing adapters to give you some additional info in the corresponding profiler panel. Is there a specific reason you need to get rid of it? Your application should not really care about the specific adapter and only rely on the interface in most cases anyway. If you need to disable it, I recommend setting `kernel.debug` to false using the `APP_DEBUG` env var.

Comment: @dbrumann thanks for the response!
`Is there a specific reason you need to get rid of it?`
Yes, it is